# Fingers don't feel thinnest strings well

Tags: guitar, practice, acoustic-guitar, strings

I learn to play acoustic guitar without a teacher, started a month ago.

I started with classic guitar and then switched to dreadnought with metallic strings.

After I developed calluses, I almost don't feel its thinnest strings when pressing them against fretboard. And it makes harder for me to place fingertips correctly, as I don't feel when finger is shifted toward another string.

Is that OK and I just have to always watch on my fingers position until muscle memory is fine? Or should I set thicker strings set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that if you can feel the strings even a little bit, you should keep the gauge you originally prefered. Then develop muscle memory, which in my opinion is more useful for playing guitar (or most instruments).

In my personal way of playing, the main sensory input is sound. Spatial awareness plays a greater role than touch, because it is hard for me to unambigously identify the region of the fretboard by touch.